# What email addresses to use for ALS?

Tags: azure-lab-services

We are trying to use Azure Lab Services for running training courses.

Log in requires a Microsoft account. We created mailboxes in our domain but Microsoft wouldn't accept 'work' email addresses for Microsoft accounts.

Next we created outlook.com email addresses but after a short while Microsoft locked out these accounts for some sort of policy violation.

Then we used some Gmail addresses which we have had for some time. These too worked for a few days and then Microsoft locked them out for a policy violation.

The policy violation must have been related to having multiple accounts with some of the same recovery information. The accounts were used for nothing other than as a way of accessing Azure Lab Services.

So we can't use work email addresses, Outlook.com email addresses or Gmail addresses. That leaves us having to ask course attendees to use their own personal email address to register a Microsoft account in order to attend a training course being provided by their employer. Some people won't mind but I'm sure some will object on principal.

Has anyone else come across this issue and found a workable solution? It is strange that a product like Azure Lab Services which is surely aimed at a lot of businesses has such a low level blocker in the way of making it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Lab Services allow you to use AAD account or Microsoft accounts. If you are trying to use your non-Microsoft account such as Yahoo or Google accounts to sign in to the portal, create a Microsoft account that will be linked to your non-Microsoft account. Then, follow the steps to complete the registration process. Could you please elaborate on how your work email accounts are configured? Ideally, you should be able to create a Microsoft account linked with the work addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create AAD accounts and use those accounts to login to Azure Labs. It seems to be working OK now...fingers crossed.